# How do I know when to use a map server or a tile server?

Tags: mapserver, tiles, rendering, tilemill

I'm new in GIS tech and I still have some questions about GIS.

I wanted to know why to choose a map server (MapServer, geomap) instead of a tile server (tilestream, tilecache or tilestache)  + tile renderer (Mapnik)?

I know that a server map use spatial data from a DB, it generate image that can be read by client map library (OpenLayers...). 
For example if I have a shapefiles and I don't need dynamic data, what the point to use a server map?

There is no need if I have a static map to have a server map, is that true?

When does a map server regenerate map, does it have a cache?

What is the format of the generated tile ?

If I choose a map server, how can I style my map? does it have a soft like in Tilemill or do I have to do it directly in the code?

Does anyone know software which does coloring like tilemill? or do I have to use cartoCSS or cascadenik to do it?

I a bit confused about that, so if anyone got the answer or think I misunderstood something, it would be great to share it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would depend on your needs and available resources. You can use both a map server and a tile server. For example, Geoserver comes with [Geowebcache](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.0/user/webadmin/server/geowebcache.html), a tile server.

> I know that a server map use spatial data from a DB, it generate image
>   that can be read by client map library (openlayer ...). For example if
>   I have a shapefiles and I don't need dynamic data, what the point to
>   use a server map ? There is no need if I have a static map to have a
>   server map, is that true ? When does a map server regenerate map, does
>   it have a cache ? What is the format of the generated tile ?

I think you just answered your question there ;-) If your data does not change much, then a tile server would be good enough. For dynamic data then you'd most probably want a map server.

> If I choose a map server, how can I style my map ? does it have a soft
>   like in Tilemill or do I have to do it directly in the code ?

That would depend on which map server you'll pick. Geoserver uses [Styled Layer Descriptors to style its layers](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/index.html). You can set this using Geoserver's web interface. Mapserver on the other hand, includes styling information on its [mapfil](http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/)e.

> Does anyone know soft which does coloring like tilemill ? or do I have
>   to use cartoCSS or cascadenik to do it ?

If you're going to use Geoserver, there are some GUI that could help you with the styling. Admittedly though, none are as pretty as Tilemill. You might want to check this [thread on  styling a WMS layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17527/how-to-style-a-wms-layer) for ideas. I don't know about the tools for Mapserver. I hope somebody would post an answer regarding it.

I hope that clarifies some things for you.